# What do i need to connect old laptop to new tv?

Tags: adapter

The screen on my old laptop does not light up all I want is to connect my  laptop to my hdtv so I can see to save my music and pictures. What do I need? The laptop has usb 2.0 and VGA

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SuperUser! There's not a lot of info here for anyone to help answer your question - it may be helpful if you included more info on your laptop - things like the OS at least, since all of them handle extra screens differently.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that your TV has an HDMI port - which it should and  you want a VGA to HDMI converter (possibly with an HDMI-HDMI cable).

Something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/VGA-To-HDMI-Output-1080P-HD-USB-Audio-TV-AV-HDTV-Video-Cable-Converter-Adapter-/301759830254) should work.